# Using CTE in a DELETE is not executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

Here is the original query that runs and runs:

```
;WITH includedCs_cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT 
            x.PKey, 
            x.OKey,
            y.CKey 
    FROM  
            #Permissions x
            JOIN WHDATA.dbo.tb_DimC y
                    ON 
                    x.PKey = y.PKey AND
                    x.OKey = y.OKey
        )
, b_cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT
            i.OKey,
            i.PKey
    FROM 
                WHData.dbo.vw_FactCX b
                INNER JOIN includedCs_cte i
                        ON 
                        b.PKey = i.PKey AND
                        b.PlayCKey = i.CKey
    WHERE b.DateKey >= @myLAST28DAYS
    GROUP BY
            i.OKey,
            i.PKey
    )
, POK_cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT
            i.OKey,
            i.PKey
    FROM 
                WHData.dbo.vw_FactCY b
                INNER JOIN includedCs_cte i
                        ON 
                        b.PKey = i.PKey AND
                        b.PlayCKey = i.CKey
    WHERE b.DateKey >= @myLAST28DAYS
    GROUP BY
            i.OKey,
            i.PKey
    )
, includedOKeys
    AS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM b_cte
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM POK_cte
    )
DELETE FROM #Permissions
FROM #Permissions p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
                    (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM includedOKeys x
                    WHERE 
                            p.PKey = x.PKey AND
                            p.OKey = x.OKey     
                    )
```

If I change the above to the below then it runs in less than 10 seconds. Why are these executing so differently?

```
;WITH includedCs_cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT 
            x.PKey, 
            x.OKey,
            y.CKey 
    FROM  
            #Permissions x
            JOIN WHDATA.dbo.tb_DimC y
                    ON 
                    x.PKey = y.PKey AND
                    x.OKey = y.OKey
        )
, b_cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT
            i.OKey,
            i.PKey
    FROM 
                WHData.dbo.vw_FactCX b
                INNER JOIN includedCs_cte i
                        ON 
                        b.PKey = i.PKey AND
                        b.PlayCKey = i.CKey
    WHERE b.DateKey >= @myLAST28DAYS
    GROUP BY
            i.OKey,
            i.PKey
    )
, POK_cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT
            i.OKey,
            i.PKey
    FROM 
                WHData.dbo.vw_FactCY b
                INNER JOIN includedCs_cte i
                        ON 
                        b.PKey = i.PKey AND
                        b.PlayCKey = i.CKey
    WHERE b.DateKey >= @myLAST28DAYS
    GROUP BY
            i.OKey,
            i.PKey
    )
, includedOKeys
    AS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM b_cte
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM POK_cte
    )
SELECT *
INTO #includedOKeys
FROM includedOKeys
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_inclProdOper ON #includedOKeys(OKey, PKey)

DELETE FROM #Permissions
FROM #Permissions p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #includedOKeys x
        WHERE 
            p.PKey = x.PKey AND
            p.OKey = x.OKey     
        )
```

Comment: Execution plan can reveal the mystery, and most probably because SQL create variable table in memory for CTE where as in second one you create temporary table for it.

Comment: The specific answer here depends upon how different these perform if you don't create the clustered index in your second example.  Beyond that, there is a lot of info available if you search for "temp table vs table variable vs cte" or something similar.

Comment: @010001100110000101110010011010, table variables may be written to tempdb as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CTE is resolved when it is used. It means that if you use it twice in a query, it may get resolved twice.  CTEs do **not always** get resolved once and cache in memory.  SQL Server is free to execute the query as it sees fit.

In your case, it may be worse than that - because you have used it as a correlated subquery in an EXISTS clause, which is a row-by-row operation.  This probably means the plan results in the CTE being resolved for ***EACH ROW*** of the #permissions table!  That could well be where all the time will be going.  Show Execution Plan (Ctrl-L) in SSMS is your friend here.

Check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5575/0), which shows that NONE of the GUIDs are the same, even though the CTE only creates 3 rows.  In fact, we get 18 distinct GUIDs.

```
with cte(guid,other) as (
  select newid(),1 union all
  select newid(),2 union all
  select newid(),3)
select a.guid, a.other, b.guid guidb, b.other otherb
from cte a
cross join cte b
order by a.other, b.other;
```

Comment: But they aren't always resolved twice either. Another [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5577) (with 40 instead of 3) with a different execution plan (and not 2x40x40 different GUIDs).

Comment: True, edited the answer. I didn't mention where it doesn't do that, as I was gearing the answer towards what is probably happening to the OP's query.

Comment: if I amend the query so it uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `NOT EXISTS` then it still hangs ...wouldn't have thought that a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` was row-by-row ?

Comment: Have you seen my query? It's a cross join. Each row in the former was materialized against each row of the other. Which caused both sides to re-render all rows independently. Like I said, no two guids were the same. Have you tried Show Execution Plan? You can edit the image into the question